# Directly setting values of struct tm's attributes not working

Tags: c++, c, strftime, ctime

Why does `asctime(ptr)` return nothing?  All the variables of the struct have values. Can someone explain why does this happen?

I also tried using `strftime` but the result was the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <new>
//#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct tm *ptr=new struct tm;
    //char buf[50];

    ptr->tm_hour=0;
    ptr->tm_mon=0;
    ptr->tm_year=0;
    ptr->tm_mday=0;
    ptr->tm_sec=0;
    ptr->tm_yday=0;
    ptr->tm_isdst=0;
    ptr->tm_min=0;
    ptr->tm_wday=0;

    cout << asctime(ptr);
    //strftime(buf,sizeof(char)*50,"%D",ptr);
    //printf("%s",buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is exactly `return nothing`?

Comment: What do you mean by return nothing? Also, 0 is not valid value for some of the members of `tm` structure. In that case it would return `NULL`.

Comment: mday cannot be 0 you are right...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below program works. Remove zero with 1 and it will work.

```
    struct tm *ptr = new struct tm();
char buf[50];

ptr->tm_hour = 1;
ptr->tm_mon = 1;
ptr->tm_year = 1;
ptr->tm_mday = 1;
ptr->tm_sec = 1;
ptr->tm_yday = 1;
ptr->tm_isdst = 1;
ptr->tm_min = 1;
ptr->tm_wday = 1;
cout << asctime(ptr)
```

This also works:

```
 ptr->tm_hour = 0;
ptr->tm_mon = 0;
ptr->tm_year = 0;
ptr->tm_mday = 1;
ptr->tm_sec = 0;
ptr->tm_yday = 0;
ptr->tm_isdst = 0;
ptr->tm_min = 0;
ptr->tm_wday = 0;

cout << asctime(ptr);
```

Comment: aren't zeros valid values for all the attributes? Why is it not working with zeros?

Comment: AFAIK day and month parameter can not be set to zero. I would suggest to do some google to do some find out

Comment: @Spanky: the encoding for month is 0 = January to 11 = December (so you can have an array of month names, without a dummy entry at index 0).  Day of month should be 1..31.  Setting `tm_year = 0` implies year 1900; the year is offset by 1900.  It might be informative to run `mktime(ptr);` and then print the structure; that normalizes the values.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `asctime` is undefined if any member of `struct tm` is outside its normal range.

Especially the behavior is undefined if the calendar day is less than 0 (some implementations handle `tm_mday==0` as meaning the last day of the preceding month).

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/asctime and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm for further details.